# How to select uncommon rows from two large files using linux (in terminal)?

Tags: linux

Both have two columns: names and IDs.`(files are in xls or txt format)`

```
File 1:
AAA K0125
ccc K0234
BMN_a K0567
BMN_c K0567

File 2:
AKP K0897
BMN_a K0567
ccc K0234
```

I want to print uncommon rows using these two files.
how can it be done using linux terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
join "-t " -j 1 -v 1 file1 file2
```

Considering the two files are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

First `sort` both the files and then use `comm` utility with `-3` option

```
sort file1 > file1_sorted
sort file2 > file2_sorted
comm -3 file1_sorted file2_sorted
```

A portion from `man comm`

```
-3 suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Output:

```
AAA K0125
    AKP K0897
BMN_c K0567
```